# interpolation of variables with different lengths

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, interpolation

I have two data.frames one with pollen (p1) and another SST (s1) both against Depth. But the STT data.frame has the double of the samples and I (think?) do need to interpolate the SST values to fit with the pollen depths.
I have tried a code suggested in a another question but I wasn't so successful.

```
> s1
# A tibble: 295 x 2
   Depth   SST
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  10.0  14.6
 2  15.0  15.3
 3  20.0  15.6
 4  25.0  15.7
 5  30.0  15.7
 6  35.0  16.1
 7  40.0  16.0
 8  45.0  16.0
 9  50.0  15.8
10  55.0  16.0
# ... with 285 more rows

> p1
# A tibble: 143 x 1
   Depth
   <dbl>
 1  20.0
 2  30.0
 3  40.0
 4  50.0
 5  60.0
 6  70.0
 7  75.0
 8  90.0
 9 100  
10 110  
# ... with 133 more rows
```

I  tried to replicate an available code and look some other answers ...but because I am quite inexperienced I just got a NULL result!

Can anyone help me, please! thank you in advance!

Comment: Is p1 supposed to have something more than just the depth?

Comment: nrow(x) checks how long each one is. Is there a common field which they can be left_join too? Then you may interpolate?

Comment: link the other question you speak of, it will help us grasp your meaning.

Comment: P1 has several pollen variables which I think are not relevant for the question.  S1 has 295 rows/Depth and P1 143 rows/Depth. The other answer didn't help at all (I look at interpolation of values btw variables of different lengths or something similar). I want to fit (by interpolation) the values of SST (295 rows) from S1 into the 143 depth rows of P1 . The end result should be something contain the 143 rows/depth of P1 with 143 interpolated values of STT (from S1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`fit <- with(s1, smooth.spline(x = Depth, y = SST))`

and

`predict(fit, x=p1$Depth)`

Don't have `dput` to load your tibble and, since I don't use it, I'm hoping the `data.frame` syntax works here.

Comment: It worked thank you AdamO! Just need to check if the smooth.spline is the best option!